# Azure Web Apps - how to run script before deployment

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to use Azure Web Apps (Linux) to host a basic static site. I configured everything so a new deployment happens with every Git push. I put my pre-built pages in my repo to confirm everything works fine with this setup.

Now I've removed the pre-built pages and kept only the templates and the build script (which is basically just an `npm install` and a mustatic 'compile') and I'd like to run this build script in my web app. I've scoured the internet but can't find anything.

How can I run a script upon first deployment and after each Git-push-triggered deployment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How can I run a script upon first deployment and after each Git-push-triggered deployment?

First, you need to generate custom deployment script by using [azure-cli](https://github.com/Azure/azure-xplat-cli) tool.

1) Set the cli working mode to `asm`.

```
azure config mode asm
```

2) Run the custom deployment script generator command.

```
azure site deploymentscript --node -t bash
```

This will generate the files required to deploy your site.

- ***.deployment*** - Contains the command to run for deploying your site.
- ***deploy.sh***   - Contains the deployment script.

Now you can edit the `deploy.cmd` file and add your custom steps.

After that done, add the generated files to your repository (.deployment and deploy.sh) and push your repository to your Azure Web App and see your custom deployment running.

[image]

For more details, please refer to [this blog post](http://blog.amitapple.com/post/38418009331/azurewebsitecustomdeploymentpart2/#.WTjcOmh96Ul).